# Mapping integers with data types?

Tags: python

I'm working on something that reads data from binary files. Data formats are often stored as integers that correspond to different types, and I typically interpret them by putting the possible types into tuples and indexing into them. Imagine A, B, and C are classes:

```
types = (A, B, C)
val = 0 # this would be read from the file
dataType = types[val]
```

Recently, I saw something that looked like a cleaner alternative to this online, but I can't remember anything specific about it and I haven't been able to find it again. This seems fine to me, but now I'm curious, is there a better way out there?

Comment: What you seem to be talking about is called **deserialisation**, i.e. loading structured data from a file or network source. It is a very wide topic, but you can search for information using that keyword. You should also read the docs for the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module, which is part of the standard library.

Comment: Can't see any places that should (may) be improved in provided code.

Comment: To read a binary file, it would be typical to use `unpack` from the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#module-struct) module.

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of enums, which can be accessed through the `enum` module.

[python docs for enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum)

```
>>> import enum
>>> class Types(enum.Enum):
...     A = 1
...     B = 2
...     C = 3
...
>>> Types(1)
<Types.A: 1>
>>> Types(2)
<Types.B: 2>
>>> Types.B
<Types.B: 2>
>>> Types.C
<Types.C: 3>
```

You might also be thinking of a `namedtuple` from the `collections` module

[python docs for named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

```
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> p = Point(11, y=22)  
>>> p[0] + p[1]    
33
>>> x, y = p     
>>> x, y
(11, 22)
>>> p.x + p.y    
33
>>> p            
Point(x=11, y=22)
```

There are countless ways to represent data though and it really comes down to the project you are working on and what makes the most sense in your current situation.